# Multiple publishers and a timer to publish tf in the same node is leading to crash

Tags: publisher, ros-noetic, timer, multi-thread

## Description

I have a node that publishes 2 topics and a timer to publish TF using ros-noetic. However this setup throws an exception:

```
libpthread.so.0!__GI___pthread_mutex_lock(pthread_mutex_t * mutex) (/build/glibc-BHL3KM/glibc-2.31/nptl/pthread_mutex_lock.c:67)
libroscpp.so!ros::Publication::processPublishQueue() (Unknown Source:0)
libroscpp.so!ros::TopicManager::processPublishQueues() (Unknown Source:0)
libroscpp.so!boost::signals2::detail::signal_impl<void (), boost::signals2::optional_last_value<void>, int, std::less<int>, boost::function<void ()>, boost::function<void (boost::signals2::connection const&)>, boost::signals2::mutex>::operator()() (Unknown Source:0)
libroscpp.so!ros::PollManager::threadFunc() (Unknown Source:0)
libboost_thread.so.1.71.0![Unknown/Just-In-Time compiled code] (Unknown Source:0)
libpthread.so.0!start_thread(void * arg) (/build/glibc-BHL3KM/glibc-2.31/nptl/pthread_create.c:477)
libc.so.6!clone() (/build/glibc-BHL3KM/glibc-2.31/sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/clone.S:95)
```

That's the output of the callback stack when it throws the exception.

## Code

`Node`

```
#include <ros/ros.h>
#include <calibrate_lidars/crash.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  ros::init(argc, argv, "crash");
  calibration::Crash cal;
  ros::AsyncSpinner spinner(0);
  spinner.start();
  ros::waitForShutdown();
  return 0;
}
```

`Header file`

```
#pragma once

#include <ros/ros.h>

#include <geometry_msgs/TransformStamped.h>
#include <tf/transform_datatypes.h>
#include <tf2_ros/buffer.h>
#include <tf2_eigen/tf2_eigen.h>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_listener.h>
#include <tf2_ros/transform_broadcaster.h>
#include <tf2_geometry_msgs/tf2_geometry_msgs.h>

namespace calibration
{
class Crash
{
public:
  // Constructor
  Crash();

private:
  tf2_ros::Buffer tf_buffer_;
  tf2_ros::TransformListener tf_listener_;
  geometry_msgs::TransformStamped tf_nominal_to_operational_;
  geometry_msgs::TransformStamped tf_nominal_to_calibrated_;
  tf2_ros::TransformBroadcaster tf_broadcaster_;
  ros::Timer tf_timer_;
  ros::Publisher pub_1_;
  ros::Publisher pub_2_;

  void initializeTfs();
};

}  // namespace calibration
```

`Definition of methods`

```
#include <calibrate_lidars/crash.h>

namespace calibration
{
Crash::Crash() : tf_listener_(tf_buffer_)
{
  initializeTfs();
  pub_1_ = ros::NodeHandle().advertise<geometry_msgs::TransformStamped>("topic_1", 1, false);
  pub_2_ = ros::NodeHandle().advertise<geometry_msgs::TransformStamped>("topic_2", 1, false);
}

void Crash::initializeTfs()
{
  // initializing an identity transformation from nominal to operational frame
  tf_nominal_to_operational_.header.frame_id = "lidar_nominal_frame";
  tf_nominal_to_operational_.child_frame_id = "lidar_operational_frame";
  tf_nominal_to_operational_.transform.rotation.w = 1;
  tf_nominal_to_calibrated_ = tf_nominal_to_operational_;
  tf_nominal_to_calibrated_.child_frame_id = "lidar_calibrated_frame";
  ROS_INFO_STREAM("Init transformation from nominal to operational frame: " << tf_nominal_to_operational_);
  tf_timer_ = ros::NodeHandle().createTimer(ros::Duration(0.1),
                                            [&](const ros::TimerEvent& event)
                                            {
                                              tf_nominal_to_operational_.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
                                              tf_nominal_to_calibrated_.header.stamp = ros::Time::now();
                                              ROS_DEBUG_THROTTLE_NAMED(30, "calibration", "Sending Transforms");
                                              tf_broadcaster_.sendTransform(tf_nominal_to_operational_);
                                              tf_broadcaster_.sendTransform(tf_nominal_to_calibrated_);
                                            });
}
}  // namespace calibration
```

If I run this node, it crashes and I can't figure out a proper solution for that.
This is a minimal reproducible example.

I also tried using a customized `callbackQueue`, but it didn't solve it.